# XOR differs when running from Netbeans directly and from JAR

Tags: java

I have a JAR that takes in a textfile read the contents as string, XOR the string and write the new string into another textfile.

This is pretty straightforward. Code used to XOR is as below:

```
public String XORStr(String key, String data){
                
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)
    sb.append((char)(data.charAt(i) ^ key.charAt(i % key.length())));
    String result = sb.toString();
    return result;
}
```

Code used to read the contents from a textfile:

```
private static String readEntireFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        FileReader in = new FileReader(filename);
        StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        int read = 0;
        do {
            contents.append(buffer, 0, read);
            read = in.read(buffer);
        } while (read >= 0);
        return contents.toString();
    }
```

Now when I test this by running from Netbeans, works as normal. Now I take the JAR from the dist folder and run separately, I noticed that for some textfile, a portion of the string is XOR wrongly and shows as gibberish (I test by XOR and XOR again to test whether I get back the same string).

Any idea what's wrong, why the difference is behaviour?

Comment: XOR behaves the same whereever you run it. The problem is more likely in the part of the code that reads the file.

Comment: @Joni I not sure, but I have included the portion where I read the contents of the textfile.

Comment: Are you maybe XOR-ing control characters from the file?

Comment: The code looks OK. Try to rebuild your project and run again. If the problem persist, please try to show us the data your code fails on.

Comment: Do you test the same file when running in netbeans, or some different file?

Comment: @Joni I am using the same file for testing. That's why I am not sure why is it inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the way I read in the file contents. Managed to resolve it. The code to read the contents from a text file is as below:

```
String content = new Scanner(new File(filename), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
return content;
```